# Python: Deque[-1] = Deque.pop() giving interesting result

Tags: python, deque

I was working with a deque and was wondering why the following code works the way it does
Code:

```
import collections

d = collections.deque()
d.append("a")
d.append("b")
d[-1] += d.pop()
print(d)
```

Output:
`deque(['bb'])`

This surprised me, as I would have expected the code to result in `deque(['ab'])` instead of `deque(['bb'])`. Why did this occur?

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
d[-1] += d.pop()
```

is equal by this line

```
d[-1] = d[-1] + d.pop()
```

python first get `d[-1]` and that is `'b'`

after that run pop method for d and this method return `'b'`
at the end python set `'bb'` for `d[-1]`

if you want pop first item use `popleft()` function.

edited code:

```
from collections import deque


d = deque()

d.append("a")
d.append("b")

d[-1] = d.popleft() + d[-1]

print(d)
```

output:

```
deque(['ab'])
```

Comment: How do you know it's equal to that?

Comment: This is really well explained! I was looking at this question for a long time completely confused!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is pretty simple:

- d[-1]+=d.pop() is expanded as: d[-1] = d[-1] + d.pop()
- d[-1] picks the right most, here its b.
- d.pop() removes the right most in our case it "b" and appends to d[-1] which is also b from previous step ( makes this "bb") and places it in the d[-1] that is the right most place which is now "a" as d.pop() removed b with "bb".

This can be easily explained if you add one more to the front:

```
import collections
d = collections.deque()
d.append('z')
d.append('a')
d.append('b')
print ("d -1 pos is : "+d[-1])
d[-1]+=d.pop()
print (d)
```

output:
d -1 pos is : b
deque(['z', 'bb'])

Comment: What do you mean it "is expanded as"?

Comment: += the addition assignment operator is a short way of writing the the left most param to which the value has to be added and assigned.... This is what it I meant by expanded as : https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/addition_assignment.html

Comment: But in general they're not the same. They produce different bytecode and can have different results.

Comment: Ok I see the page you linked to says "Equivalent to A = A + B". That's simply wrong. Shameful for a site called "Python Reference (The Right Way)".

Comment: Can you shed light on when it will create different results? It adds right operand to the left operand and assign the result to left operand right??

Comment: They differ when the left operand implements `__iadd__` and modifies itself. See [example](https://repl.it/repls/TenseEminentGroupware#main.py).